# how to handle screen rotations when app is in background and user is on home screen android

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I am recording in background service.
 i want to record videos based on user mode selection.

selection modes : Portrait/ landscape-right/landscape-left

lets say i selected mode as landscape-left and app goes in background and user rotated device even if this happens i want to record video in landscape-left only;

I have tried following

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
}
```

But it seems it dosen't get event on home screen.
Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want app in  portrait mode only?

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: if yes,then add this in manifest=> <activity> tag android:screenOrientation="portrait/landscape" use one that you are required

Comment: app should work on user selection of mode. i.e if i select landscape it should record in landscape and if i select portrait it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver into your background service like:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                //configuration has changed
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

You can find more information on it in the [documention](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED).

> Broadcast Action: The current device Configuration (orientation, locale, etc) has changed. When such a change happens, the UIs (view hierarchy) will need to be rebuilt based on this new information; for the most part, applications don't need to worry about this, because the system will take care of stopping and restarting the application to make sure it sees the new changes. Some system code that can not be restarted will need to watch for this action and handle it appropriately.

Note that this intent can only be retrive from registerReceiver, NOT from the manifest via a intent filter